# ShallowWrapper is empty when running test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, enzyme

I'm new to testing so I'm trying to add Enzyme to one of my projects. My problem is that when using `find()`, the ShallowWrapper is empty. Also I'm using Material UI, so I don't know if this is part of the problem.

**The component I'm testing**

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  background: {
    backgroundColor: "#2E2E38"
  },
  title: {
    color: "#FFE600",
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

const NavBar = ({ classes }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root} data-test="nav-bar">
      <AppBar className={classes.background}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.title}>
            App
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

**The test**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

describe("NavBar component", () => {

  it("Should render without errors.", () => {
    let component = shallow(<NavBar />);
    let navbar = component.find("data-test", "nav-bar");
    console.log("Log is", component);
    expect(navbar).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your [selector](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html) in `find(selector)` to the following to target the element with `data-test="nav-bar"`. You may need to use [dive()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) to be able to access the inner components of the style component:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

describe("NavBar component", () => {

  it("Should render without errors.", () => {
    const component = shallow(<NavBar />);
    // Use dive() to access inner components
    const navbar = component.dive().find('[data-test="nav-bar"]');
    // Test that we found a single element by targeting length property
    expect(navbar.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

You can also use an object syntax if you prefer:

```
const navbar = component.find({'data-test': 'nav-bar'});
```

Alternatively to using `dive()`, you could instead `mount()` the component instead of `shallow()`, but it depends on your use case:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

describe("NavBar component", () => {

  it("Should render without errors.", () => {
    const component = mount(<NavBar />);
    // Use dive() to access inner components
    const navbar = component.find('[data-test="nav-bar"]');
    // Test that we found a single element by targeting length property
    expect(navbar.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still won't pass the test. It throws me the error: `Expected value to be (using ===): 1 Received: 0`. Don't really know what's going on.

Comment: @TheWoodStudio I update the answer. You can use `dive()` to access the inner components of this styled component.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue for a different reason where I could not find a SingleDatePicker element. The example in 2. A React Component Constructor from the documentation fixed it for me.

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#1-a-valid-css-selector

using

```
    wrapper.find(SingleDatePicker).prop('onDateChange')(now);
```

instead of

```
    wrapper.find('SingleDatePicker').prop('onDateChange')(now);
```

did the trick for me.